# How to create new controller in prestashop?

Tags: smarty, prestashop-1.6

I am newbie in Prestashop and I am wondering that how can I pass varibales to tpl file like in zend we do like this..

```
$this->view->name = $val;
```

and then we get the variable in tpl like

```
$this->name;
```

I just created the new controller and able to access the controller like

```
index.php?controller=mycontroler
```

but I do not know how can i use the controller and tpls combined like zend. I hope you understand my question.

Please let me know what if you think question is not good or not explaining well in comments.

Answer (score 2):

I hope I have understood your question.
in your Controller you can set the tpl to display and assign variables to it as in the following example:

```
class CategoryListControllerCore extends FrontController
{
    public $php_self = 'category-list';

    public function initContent()
    {
        parent::initContent();

        $value1 = 'hello;
        $value2 = 'world';
        $this->context->smarty->assign(array(
            'var1'=>$value1,
            'var2'=>$value2,
        ));
        $this->setTemplate(_PS_THEME_DIR_.'category-list.tpl');
    }
}
```

and in your tpl file you can print the variable:

```
<p>{$var1} {$var2}!</p>
```